# Indefinite integral $\int x \sin(x) a(x) dx$

Tags: calculus

Suppose  $$a'(x)=b(x)$$ and $$b'(x)=a(x)$$

What is $$\int x \sin (x) a(x) dx$$

Thanks!

Comment: Proceed with integrating by parts multiple times.

Comment: Seems like $a(x) = \sinh(x)$ or also $a(x) = \cosh(x)$

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! You are more likely to get a good answer to your question if you follow [a few guidelines](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  In particular, what have you tried so far, and just where are you stuck? This is not a homework-answering site: we want to see that you have put significant work into the problem.

Comment: A start:  $a^{\prime \prime} (x) = a(x)$ so $a(x) = \sinh(x)$ or $\cosh(x)$, as Kim Peek points out.

Answer (score 0):

Since ${\partial^2 a(x) \over \partial x^2} = a(x)$, we have

$a(x) = c1\ e^x + c2\ e^{-x}$.

Then $\int x\ \sin(x) (c1\ e^x + c2\ e^{-x})\ dx = \frac{1}{2} e^{-x} \left(\cos (x) \left(-\left(\text{c1} e^{2 x} (x-1)+\text{c2}
   (x+1)\right)\right)-x \sin (x) \left(\text{c2}-\text{c1} e^{2 x}\right)\right)$

Comment: Is there a reason for using "$\frac{\partial a}{\partial x}$" rather than "$\frac{da}{dx}$" when a is a function of a single variable?

Comment: One could use $d$ or $\partial$... no difference in this case.

Answer (score 0):

In the general case: It can be determined that $a'' = b' = a$ and the following.
\begin{align}
I &= \int x \, a(x) \, \sin(x) \, dx.
\end{align}
Using integration by parts with $dv = \sin(x)$ and $u = x \, a(x)$, where
$$\int u \, dv \, dx = u \, v - \int du \, v \, dx$$,
leads to
\begin{align}
I = - x \, a(x) \, \cos(x) + \int x \, a'(x) \, \cos(x) \, dx + \int a(x) \, \cos(x) \, dx.
\end{align}
Applying integration by parts in similar manor on the first integral, $dv = \cos(x)$ and $u = x \, a'(x)$,
\begin{align}
I = x \, (b(x) \, \sin(x) - a(x) \, \cos(x)) - I - \int (b(x) \, \sin(x) - a(x) \, \cos(x) ) \, dx
\end{align}
which is seen to be 
\begin{align}
\int x \, a(x) \, \sin(x) \, dx = \frac{1}{2} \, \left[ x \, f(x) - \int f(x) \, dx \right] 
\end{align}
where $f(x) = b(x) \, \sin(x) - a(x) \, \cos(x)$.

Now, the equations $a'(x) = b(x)$ and $b'(x) = a(x)$ lead to $a''-a = 0$ and $b'' - b=0$. Both of which have solutions of the form $c_{0} \, \cosh(x) + c_{1} \, \sinh(x)$. Under certain parameter choices the form of $f(x)$ can be reduced to readily known forms for easier computations.